# Match heights of children within each parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put together a piece of Jquery which will find the children of a parent and make the children the same height as the tallest child within the parent.

This is going wrong because the height is being matched across all children and should be being applied to each parent uniquely.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swHWh.png)

As you can see above, the full width columns height is matching that of the bottom right 50% column. This shouldn't be happening, the full width column should be applying its own height.

```js
var colHeight = 0;
$('div.column-holder').children().each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > colHeight) {
    colHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});
$("div.column").height(colHeight);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column-holder">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="shadow bg-white">
      <div class="bdr-top-blue"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My mistake.

I have edited the post and added in the variable for colHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should iterate over parents rather than all children. This way you can calculate the max height per parent

```js
$('div.column-holder').each(function() {
  var parent = $(this);
  var maxHeight = 0;
  parent.children().each(function() {
     if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
         maxHeight = $(this).height();
     }
  });
  parent.find("div.column").height(maxHeight);
 });
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion and a working solution.

Thank you for your help!